# Web Font Loader - when have all fonts loaded?

Tags: javascript, commonjs, webfont-loader

I'm using web font loader as a module:

```
var WebFont = require('webfontloader');

  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    }
 });
```

How can I find out when all fonts are active?

I've tried adding:

```
WebFontConfig = {
    active: function() {
        console.log('fonts ok');
    }
}
```

But get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WebFontConfig is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
var WebFont = require('webfontloader');

  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    },
    active: function(){ 
        //when fonts loaded
        console.log('fonts loaded');
    }
 });
```

Comment: After looking on GH, probably due to: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader/issues/301